# MySQL how to find rows with suffix

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to sort out only rows which has identical title but (2), (3), (38) or etc. at the ending.

I've tried something like

```
SELECT * FROM `rows` WHERE `title` LIKE '%(%'
```

But it's not always accurate.

```
Australia (16)
United States (Of America)
India (3)
```

I need only those with numbers at the ending.

Comment: could you provide some sample data, particularly the one that fails your query?

Comment: Sure. Edited my first post.

Comment: could you also share your dbms, for example, SQL server, MySQL etc

Comment: I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to work with [REGEXP_LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html)

```sql
SELECT * FROM rows
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(title, '\\(\\d+\\)$');
```

Answer (score 1):

The query will be somewhat slow because you are filtering by suffixes rather then prefixes but you can use [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

```sql
SELECT * FROM rows WHERE title REGEXP '\\(\\d+\\)$'
```

Comment: For some reason it didn't found any rows at all.